# Send a url between 2 NFC devices

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p

I have an android application with a webview in it. 
When the webview is getting to url with certain text, e.g. ticket, then I would like to send the url to another NFC device through NFC.
I was able to send the url to the type 4 NFC tag, but I am not able to find out how to send it to other NFC device so that it will launch the browser with the url.
I was just using the following to create the NDEF

```
NdefRecord uriRecord = NdefRecord.createUri(url);
NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {
            uriRecord            
});
```

and then use this to write

```
ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
```

I am writing the app in ICS (on galaxy nexus) and trying to send to the galaxy s2 with 2.3.6.

Any help and pointer will be appreciated.

Comment: does galaxy s2 have NFC chip?

Comment: yes, it does, I was able to read a nfc tag on galaxy s2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending an NDEF message to another phone, you don't use a tag read/write API such as `Ndef`. Instead, your NDEF message is delivered via NFC peer-to-peer. One way to do that is to use [`setNdefPushMessageCallback`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#setNdefPushMessageCallback%28android.nfc.NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.app.Activity...%29) in your `Activity`'s `onCreate()`:

```
    NfcAdapter nfc = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    nfc.setNdefPushMessageCallback(new NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback()
    {
        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.nfc.NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback#createNdefMessage(android.nfc.NfcEvent)
         */
        @Override
        public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) 
        {
            NdefRecord uriRecord = NdefRecord.createUri(Uri.encode("http://www.google.com/"));
            return new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { uriRecord });
        }

    }, this, this);
```

The callback will be called when another NFC device comes near and a peer-to-peer connection is established. The callback then creates the NDEF message to be sent (in your case: the URL displayed in the webview).

Comment: Thank you, it works! I did find that the "connection" is kind of unstable between galaxy nexus 4.04 and galaxy S2 2.36. But in general, i was able to transfer the url.

Comment: You want to experiment somewhat with positioning the devices vertically relative to each other so the NFC antennas line up properly.

Comment: but how do you send multiple messages without disconnecting?

Comment: You can't :( That is a current limitation of the Android API, unfortunately.

Comment: @Pittfall you can only send one NdefMessage but it can contain multiple NDEF records. Maybe that helps...
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefMessage.html#NdefMessage(android.nfc.NdefRecord[])

Comment: setNdefPushMessageCallback is depracated